# Accessing controller from model

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller, delegates

I have the following class design:

- A controller class and a model class both inherited from NSobject;
- A UI which has IBoutlets from controller;
- A model class which scans a set of files for their properties and writes to a file (using a loop);
- the UI must display the name of the current file being scanned .

How can i make the model class  communicate with the controller?

I have made an object of the model inside the controller so to avoid circularity I cannot make an instance of controller inside the model class .  Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Define a protocol in the model's .h something like this:

```
@protocol FileScannerDelegate
@required
    - (void)fileScanner:(FileScannerClass *)fileScanner willScanFile:(NSString *);
@end
```

Add a new property that is `assign` to hold a reference to the delegate. This needs to be assign to avoid a circular reference

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<FileScannerDelegate> delegate;
```

In the model .m at the point where you are scanning the next file you call

```
[delegate fileScanner:self willScanFile:fileName];
```

In the controller's .h you need to say that you follow the protocol

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <FileScannerDelegate>
```

In the controller .m. When you instantiate the file scanner in your controller you need to set the controller as the delegate

```
fileScanner = [[FileScannerClass alloc] init];
fileScanner.delegate = self;
```

Then implement the method you said you would

```
- (void)fileScanner:(FileScannerClass *)fileScanner willScanFile:(NSString *)
{
   ...
   // update the UI
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide the model with a reference to the controller.

```
@class MyController

@interface MyModel:NSObject

@property (readwrite,assign) MyController *controller;

@end
```

and implement

```
#include "MyController.h"    

@implementation MyModel

@synthesize controller;

-(void)somethingHappenedToMe
 {
      [controller updateYourself:self];
 }


@end
```

You can abstract yourself up the wazoo with delegates and private methods but at the end of the day you still want your model instance to talk to your controller instance.

Comment: It's not much more typing to implement the protocol and it gives you a much more robust end solution by providing a contract through which the two objects talk. Throwing caution to the wind may work 99% of the time but it does not scale and the 1% will come back to bite you with difficult bugs.